# How can I prevent PC from shutting down while charging a phone/tablet?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, windows-11, power-management

My windows 11 desktop seems to be shutting down after connected devices reach full charge. Motherboard is Asus Crosshair Hero VIII. I haven’t been able to find a post about this issue specifically.

This only occurs when the PC is sleeping while charging the secondary device and after that device has reached full charge. I charge iPhone and iPad with the front panel USB-C port.

Comment: Go you mean that charging phones when Windows is sleeping, the sleep becomes shutdown when charging is complete?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: [Create a Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) and post online the HTML file for us (OneDrive, Dropbox etc). Using hibernate rather than sleep might at least avoid the problem.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/m3i97dvh1askdq6ovrrmg/energy-report.html?rlkey=9jg9fltaoky9cr4n123tppb2c&dl=0

Comment: Try [this method](https://www.pcworld.com/article/420146/how-to-keep-charging-your-usb-devices-past-your-pcs-bedtime.html).

Comment: Thank you, but that’s not the issue I have. My devices will charge from the USB ports even when the machine is turned off. My issue is the shutdown seemingly being triggered by the connected device reaching full charge. I then am unable to wake my machine remotely. 

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm unaware of such a feature in Windows. Before putting the computer to sleep, could you boot into Safe Mode and leave it sleeping and charging? It's interesting to know if it will shutdown again.